# One to many relationship, view using References module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm using the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references) in Drupal 7 to do the following: I have projects and clients (content types), so that a project can belong to many clients, and a client can have many projects. I set this up using a `Node reference` field on the `Project` content type, which accepts unlimited values. What I need is a view ([Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views)) that shows a list of clients, and inside each one the projects that belong to it, like this:

```
Client 1
  - project 1
  - project 2

Client 2
  (no projects)

Client 3
  - project 45
  - project 2
```

With links to the projects' pages.

I don't know how the view should be set up. I tried using the `User aggregation` option in the `Advanced` section of the view editor, with no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a contextual filter of `client field` in project view page. Go to client view and add `Content: Nid` and a `Global: Custom text field`.  In Custom text field go to `custom text rewrite results` -> and  `select Output this field as a link`. In `Link path` give value as `page_to_list_projects/[nid]`.

Basically we are passing client nid as argument to the project list page and filtering projects with client nid.